# Tips for optimizing X_transpose*X CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda

I am writing my first CUDA application and am writing all the kernels my self for practice.

In one portion I am simply calculating X_transpose * X.

I have been using cudaMallocPitch and cudaMemcpy2D, I first allocate enough space on the device for X and X_transpose*X. I copy X to the device, my kernel takes two inputs, the X matrix, then the space to write the X_transpose * X result.

Using the profiler the kernel originally took 104 seconds to execute on a matrix of size 5000x6000. I pad the matrix with zeros on the host so that it is a multiple of the block size to avoid checking the bounds of the matrix in the kernel. I use a block size of 32 by 32.

I made some changes to try to maximize coalesced reads/writes to global memory, this seemed to help significantly. Using the visual profiler to profile the release build of my code, the kernel now takes 4.27 seconds to execute.

I haven't done an accurate timing of my matlab execution(just the operation X'*X;), but it appears to be about 3 seconds. I was hoping I could get much better speedups than matlab using CUDA.

The nvidia visual profiler is unable to find any issues with my kernel, I was hoping the community here might have some suggestions as to how I can make it go faster.

The kernel code:

```
__global__ void XTXKernel(Matrix X, Matrix XTX) {

//find location in output matrix
int blockRow = blockIdx.y;
int blockCol = blockIdx.x;

int row = threadIdx.y;
int col = threadIdx.x;

Matrix XTXsub = GetSubMatrix(XTX, blockRow, blockCol);
float Cvalue = 0;

for(int m = 0; m < (X.paddedHeight / BLOCK_SIZE); ++m) {

    //Get sub-matrix
    Matrix Xsub = GetSubMatrix(X, m, blockCol);
    Matrix XTsub = GetSubMatrix(X, m, blockRow);

    __shared__ float Xs[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
    __shared__ float XTs[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];

    //Xs[row][col] = GetElement(Xsub, row, col);
    //XTs[row][col] = GetElement(XTsub, col, row);
    Xs[row][col] = *(float*)((char*)Xsub.data + row*Xsub.pitch) + col;
    XTs[col][row] = *(float*)((char*)XTsub.data + row*XTsub.pitch) + col;

    __syncthreads();

    for(int e = 0; e < BLOCK_SIZE; ++e)
        Cvalue += Xs[e][row] * XTs[col][e];

    __syncthreads();
}

//write the result to the XTX matrix
//SetElement(XTXsub, row, col, Cvalue);
((float *)((char*)XTXsub.data + row*XTX.pitch) + col)[0] = Cvalue;
}
```

The definition of my Matrix structure:

```
struct Matrix {
matrixLocation location;
unsigned int width;             //width of matrix(# cols)
unsigned int height;            //height of matrix(# rows)
unsigned int paddedWidth;       //zero padded width
unsigned int paddedHeight;      //zero padded height
float* data;                    //pointer to linear array of data elements
size_t pitch;               //pitch in bytes, the paddedHeight*sizeof(float) for host, device determines own pitch
size_t size;                //total number of elements in the matrix
size_t paddedSize;          //total number of elements counting zero padding
};
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I am running the on a Kepler card, GTX 670 4GB.

Comment: http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs675/MatrixTranspose.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Smaller block size like 16x16 or 8x8 may be faster. [This slides](http://coachk.cs.ucf.edu/courses/CDA6938/s08/matrix_multiplication_hongliang.ppt) also demos larger non-square size of block/shared mem may be faster for particular matrix size.
2. For shared mem allocation, add a dumy element on the leading dimension by using `[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE+1]` to avoid the bank conflict.
3. Try to unroll the inner for loop by using `#pragma unroll`

On the other hand, You probably won't be much faster than matlab GPU code for large enough A'*A. Since the performance bottleneck of matlab is the invoking overhead rather than the kernel performance.

The cuBLAS routine `culas_gemm()` may have highest performance for matrix multiplication. You could compare yours with it.

[MAGMA](https://developer.nvidia.com/magma) routine `magma_gemm()` has higher performance than cuBLAS in some cases. It's a open source project. You may also get some ideas from their code.